# Why is parent not reaping child?

Tags: c

I am writing code that forks a process into two, then the parent sends the arguments to main through a pipe to the child. The child counts the characters one by one and prints the final result. The parent is then supposed to reap the child using waitpid().

If I remove the loop in the child process, then the reap will occur, but if I leave it in (this is necessary), the program executes and terminates, but the reap does not occur. I don't know why this is. Any help will be appreciated. This is homework for a class. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
    if( waitpid( pid, &status, WNOHANG ) > 0 )
        {
        printf( "parent reaps child status 0x%08X\n", status );
        if( WIFEXITED(status) )
        printf( "child exited normally with %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status) );
    }
    close( out );
    return 0;
```

Also I realize there is no error checking in this code...I was just trying to get it to work first...

Comment: Or, in other words, "Why is this parent not raping child?"

Comment: What a horrible title. :(

Comment: lmao...wow how did I not see that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell the client when to stop, which you do by closing the pipe. So the parent process must do:

```
for( i = 0; i < (argc - 1); i++ )
{
    for( idx = 0; idx < strlen(argv[i + 1]); idx++ )
        write( out, &argv[i + 1][idx], 1 );
}
close(out);  // <----
sleep(1);
if( waitpid( pid, &status, WNOHANG ) > 0 )
```

Also, WNOHANG tells waitpid to not wait if the child process isn't finished. So in your case it isn't finished.

```
waitpid( pid, &status, WNOHANG )
                       ^^^^
```

Comment: and I guess I can't upvote nos until I have 15 reputation...Sorry!